# I would like to call in 5 random php include files

Tags: php, arrays

I have this so far

```
<?php
    $pagesToLoad = array("file1.php","file2.php","file3.php","file4.php","file5.php","file6.php","file7.php","file8.php","file9.php","file10.php");

    $randomPageToLoadA = $pagesToLoad[mt_rand(0, count($pagesToLoad) -1)];
    $randomPageToLoadB = $pagesToLoad[mt_rand(0, count($pagesToLoad) -1)];
    $randomPageToLoadC = $pagesToLoad[mt_rand(0, count($pagesToLoad) -1)];
    $randomPageToLoadD = $pagesToLoad[mt_rand(0, count($pagesToLoad) -1)];
    $randomPageToLoadE = $pagesToLoad[mt_rand(0, count($pagesToLoad) -1)];
?>
```

Then i have 5 blocks that should load up any 5 of the random files like this

```
<?php
    include($randomPageToLoadA);
    include($randomPageToLoadB);
    include($randomPageToLoadC);
    include($randomPageToLoadD);
    include($randomPageToLoadE);
?>
```

The concern i have is that it could load in the same page in 2 of the blocks, is there a way around this.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand) with second parameter:

```
$keys = array_rand($pagesToLoad, 5);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    include $pagesToLoad[$key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this would have worked for me too but i think in my particular case the shuffle idea worked easier for me, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomly order the array and then display first 5 elements wherever you want.

Comment: Brilliant thanks so much, this was much easier than anticipated, wonderful.